# what is this formatting [something like json]?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

I wanna develop web site which read some data from air time api.

it generate something like following:

```
({"env":"production","schedulerTime":"2012-07-11 14:44:34","previous":{"name":"Written By: Jalale Ale Ahmad - Modire Madrese [www.audiolib.ir]","starts":"2012-07-11 09:30:48.228571","ends":"2012-07-11 10:01:00.087571","type":"track"},"current":{"name":"Written By: Jalale Ale Ahmad - Modire Madrese [www.audiolib.ir]","starts":"2012-07-11 10:01:00.087571","ends":"2012-07-11 10:31:11.217571","media_item_played":true,"record":0,"type":"track"},"next":{"name":"Written By: Jalale Ale Ahmad - Modire Madrese [www.audiolib.ir]","starts":"2012-07-11 10:31:11.217571","ends":"2012-07-11 11:01:17.567071","type":"track"},"currentShow":[{"start_timestamp":"2012-07-11 13:58:00","end_timestamp":"2012-07-11 16:00:00","name":"Untitled Show","id":36,"instance_id":36,"record":0,"url":"","starts":"2012-07-11 13:58:00","ends":"2012-07-11 16:00:00"}],"nextShow":[],"timezone":"IRDT","timezoneOffset":"16200","AIRTIME_API_VERSION":"1.0"})
```

it's not JSON ,so what is that? and How should I convert it to php or javascript array?

Comment: it looks like json to me

Comment: Why do you think it's not JSON?

Comment: Maybe JSONP without the function name. That might happen if you don't pass a `callback` parameter in the URL and they don't provide a default function name. I suggest to read the API documentation. If this is the only output they provide, simply strip the leading and trailing parenthesis.

Comment: What @Felix said. Check if you're using the API correctly, there's probably a JSON-only instead of JSONP API too.

Answer (score 2):

it seems to be valid JSON..check it in http://jsonlint.com/...

You can convert it to array using `json_decode($output, true);`

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be json(just get rid of the first round bracket).

you can use the below free on line tool to validate it

http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely JSON. You just have to skip the round brackets at the beginning and end of the data. The json_decode PHP function should be able to decode it for you then.

Answer (score 1):

While it is not valid JSON, it looks like JSON with extra parenthesis around it. As Felix mentioned, could be a JSON-P-packaged response without function name. Either check API documentation on how to supply it or, if you can post-process data after receiving and before passing to JSON.parse, just remove `()` manually.